# Migrate SVN branches subfolders to Git

Tags: git, svn, migration, branch, svn2git

I'm using `svn2git` but I could use `git svn` as well. I had the scenario below in the SVN repository.

```
 trunk 
 brances 
     branchesA
         branchA1
         branchA2
         [...]
     branchesB
         branchB1
         branchB2
         [...]
     branchesX
         [...]
```

After the migration is done, on Git side there are branches `branchesA`, `branchesB`, etc... That have inside folders with the properly SVN branches. For example on Git repository:

```
 master 
 branchesA 
 branchesB 
 branchesX
 [...]
```

If you `$git checkout branchesA` you will see all branches sub folders like (`$ls`):

```
 branchA1
 branchA2
 branchA3
 [...]
```

Is there a way or tool or something that could fix this once I already migrated it, or somehow pass more then one folder to the `--branches`?

Comment: There is PR that would fix this properly but not approved yet! https://github.com/nirvdrum/svn2git/pull/65

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do **not** use `git svn` for a one-time conversion. It is gread if you need to constantly sync and also commit back to SVN, but sub-optimal for a one-time conversion.

There are pleny tools called `svn2git`, but from your question I'd guess you are not using the KDE one from https://github.com/svn-all-fast-export/svn2git. I strongly recommend using that `svn2git` tool. It is the best I know available out there and it's very flexible in what you can do with its rules files.

You will easily be able to configure it for your layout to get the result you want and expect. You can even keep the convention of having your branches in "subfolders" like you have it currently in SVN. A branch in Git would then be `branchesA/branchA1`.

If you are not 100% about the history of your repository, `svneverever` from http://blog.hartwork.org/?p=763 is a great tool to investigate the history of a SVN repository when migrating it to Git.

Comment: I'm **not** using `git svn`, I'm using the `svn2git`. I checked the links and will try it out. Thanks...

Comment: Just wanted to make sure you do not really consider it as you wrote you do consider it. And yes, you use `svn2git`, but not the one I mentioned, do you?

Comment: Unfortunately not, I'm learning how to use the KDE. Looks easier to setup a branches layout, I just need learn how to do it...

Comment: Probably something like https://gist.github.com/Vampire/f48bd7e3667a0cc0cbe1b5746c492be8

Comment: I just posted a problem in the repo, might you have a clue what's going on? https://github.com/svn-all-fast-export/svn2git/issues/3#issuecomment-214359524

Comment: Well yes, just read the comments why the issue was closed. Remote protocols are not supported, you have to have the repository as copy locally to use KDEs svn2git.